# Best practice beanstalkd (queue) and node.js

Tags: node.js, queue, message-queue, beanstalkd

I currently do service using beanstalkd and node.js.
I would like when jobs fail, retry n time before give up the job.
If the job succede i want do it the same job 10 time. 
So, what is the best practice, stock in mongo db with the jobId the error and success count, or delete and put a new job with a an error and success count in the body.

I dont know if i'm clear? so tell me , thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of ways to do this:

- you can release the job, and obtain from stats the number of reserves
- you can put a new job with a retry count, and keep track of history in the data payload

You should do the later, and you don't need MongoDB as a second dependency.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, but if i release i can't know honw many error and how many success just the number of total release no?

Comment: than you can keep track in the message json

Answer (score 1):

There is a `stats-job <id>\r\n` that should also be available via the API library that returns, among other things, how many times the specific job has been reserved, released, buried, and so on.

This allows for a number of retries of failed jobs by checking previous reservation/releases.

To run the same job multiple times, I would personally create either one additional job, with a success count that would then be incremented (into another new job) - or, all nine new jobs, with optional delays before they start.